# perl string catenation and substitution in a single line?

Tags: regex, string, perl, premature-optimization

I need to modify a perl variable containing a file path; it needs to begin and end with a forward slash (/) and have all instances of multiple forward slashes reduced to a single slash.

(This is because an existing process does not enforce a consistent configuration syntax, so there are hundreds of config files scattered everywhere that may or may not have slashes in the right places in file names and path names.)

Something like this:

```
foreach ( ($config->{'backup_path'},
           $config->{'work_path'},
           $config->{'output_path'}
         ) ) {
     $_ = "/" . $_ . "/";
     $_ =~ s/\/{2,}/\//g;
}
```

but this does not look optimal or particularly readable to me; I'd rather have a more elegant expression (if it ends up using an unusual regex I'll use a comment to make it clearer.)

**Input & output examples**

`home/datamonster//c2counts` becomes `/home/datamonster/c2counts/`

`home/////teledyne/tmp/` becomes `/home/teledyne/tmp/`

and `/var/backup/DOC/all_instruments/` will pass through unchanged

Comment: Can you give an example of input/output?

Comment: Try this: `$_ =~ s{(?:^(?!/)|(?<!/)$|/{2,})}{/}g`.. but I don't know if its more readable

Comment: @Sobrique, typically input strings will look something like "home/datamonster//c2counts" or "/home/teledyne/tmp/".  The code I'm working on is a re-engineering job so it has to be able to use existing configuration files, which are of highly variable quality ;)

Comment: Probably worth [edit]ing that into your question, along with how it should look on output, just for clarity.

Comment: You tagged this as `premature-optimisation`. So, your main point is: 1.) be readable, 2.) concise 3.) fast on execution? Just wondering...

Comment: @jm666, I was just poking fun at myself for something many people would call obsessive over-analysis of minutia.  I feel like the perl idioms I hope to learn from asking this question are more important than the actual problem itself.

Comment: @Medievalist  I don't find it excessive at all -- for one thing, a missing first slash is a gross error, it's an incorrect path.  The last slash is for me almost a matter of design, about how I want to later use these paths. The middle slash can mess up alignment in prints, what can distract when visually inspecting things.  A good idea to clean'em up, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just rewriting what you got:

```
my @vars = qw ( backup_path work_path output_path );

for ( @{$config}{@vars} ) {
   s,^/*,/,;  #prefix
   s,/*$,/,; #suffix
   s,/+,/,g; #double slashes anywhere else. 
}
```

I'd be cautious - optimising for magic regex is not an advantage in every situation, because they become quite quickly unreadable.

The above uses the [hash slice mechanism](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices) to select values out of a hash (reference in this case), and the fact that `s///` implicitly operates on `$_` anyway. And modifies the original var when it does.

But it's also useful to know, if you're operating on patterns containing `/` it's helpful to switch delimiters, because that way you don't get the "leaning toothpicks" effect.

`s/\/{2,}/\//g` can be written as:

```
s,/+,/,g
```

or

```
 s|/{2,}|/|g
```

if you want to keep the numeric quantifier, as `+` is inherently 1 or more which works the same here, because it collapses a double into a single anyway, but it *technically* matches `/` (and replaces it with `/`) where the original pattern doesn't. But you wouldn't want to use the `,` if you have that in your pattern, for the same reason.

However I think this does the trick;

```
s,(?:^/*|\b\/*$|/+),/,g for @{$config}{qw ( backup_path work_path output_path )};
```

This matches an alternation grouping, replacing either:

- start of line, zero or more `/`
- word boundary, zero or more `/` end of line
- one or more slashes anywhere else.

with a single `/`.

uses the hash slice mechanism as above, but without the intermediate 'vars'.

(For some reason the second grouping doesn't work correctly without the word boundary `\b` zero width anchor - I think this is a backtracking issue, but I'm not entirely sure)

For bonus points - you could probably select `@vars` using `grep` if your source data structure is appropriate:

```
my @vars = grep { /_path$/ } keys %$config; 
#etc. Or inline with:
s,(?:^/*|\b\/*$|/+),/,g for @{$config}{grep { /_path$/ } keys %$config };
```

Edit: Or as [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) notes:

```
s|(?:/|\A|\z)/*|/|
```

Giving us:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $config = {
   backup_path => "/fish/",
   work_path   => "narf//zoit",
   output_path => "/wibble",
   test_path => 'home/datamonster//c2counts',
   another_path => "/home/teledyne/tmp/",
   again_path => 'home/////teledyne/tmp/',
   this_path => '/var/backup/DOC/all_instruments/',
};

s,(?:/|\A|\b\z)/*,/,g for @{$config}{grep { /_path$/ } keys %$config };

print Dumper $config;
```

Results:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'output_path' => '/wibble/',
          'this_path' => '/var/backup/DOC/all_instruments/',
          'backup_path' => '/fish/',
          'work_path' => '/narf/zoit/',
          'test_path' => '/home/datamonster/c2counts/',
          'another_path' => '/home/teledyne/tmp/',
          'again_path' => '/home/teledyne/tmp/'
        };
```

Comment: That's exactly the kind of information I was looking for!  Thank you!

Comment: The need for \b is odd, though, I agree.  Isn't the slash after the \b unnecessary since the comma is being used as a delimiter?

Comment: `( $_ = "/$_/" ) =~ s|/\K/+||g` or `s|(?:/|\A|\z)/*|/|`

Comment: Yes, I didn't need to escape that slash with a comma delimiter.

Comment: I trying to understand the solution(s). In the regex `s,(?:^/*|\b\/*$|/+),/,g` why do you using word-boundary at the end of the path? e.g. you're used the `\b\/*$`. Is here some reason exclude paths like `/some/strange/path-` ?

Comment: @Borodin - I think your second pattern has the same problem as mine - it ignores trailing slashes - `home/////teledyne/tmp/` -> `/home/teledyne/tmp//` - but `s,(?:/|\A|\b\z)/*,/,g` (e.g. with a `\b`) matches/replaces that trailing slash.

Comment: @Sobrique: You're quite right. I was very lazy writing that -- I didn't even get the delimiters right! This works `s{\A/*|//+|[^/]\K/*\z}{/}g`. I don't think you can rely on the path segments being exactly `\w+`, and if they're not then `\b` won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

you could do it like this, but I wouldn't call it more readable:

```
foreach ( ($config->{'backup_path'},
           $config->{'work_path'},
           $config->{'output_path'}
         ) ) {
     ( $_ = "/$_/" ) =~ s/\/{2,}/\//g;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought that assignment syntax would work, it's nice to know I'm still remembering some of perl correctly!

Answer (score 0):

This question already got many fantastic answers.

From the view of non-perl-expert (me), some are hard to read / understand. ;)

So, I would probably use this:

```
my @vars = qw ( backup_path work_path output_path );
for my $var (@vars) {
    my $value = '/' . $config->{$var} . '/';
    $value =~ s|//+|/|g;
    $config->{$var} = $value;
}
```

For me, this is will be readable after a year too. :)

Comment: Readability is important. Sometimes implicit variables help, sometimes they don't, so go with what works for you. Clarity is _much_ more important than being 'concise' or 'clever' (most of those get optimised by the compiler anyway)