# Regex - zero width 'word boundary' makes an alternation pattern match correctly

Tags: regex, perl

With reference to: [perl string catenation and substitution in a single line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43211967/perl-string-catenation-and-substitution-in-a-single-line/43212333#43212333)

Given an input of:

```
home/////test/tmp/
```

And a desired transform to:

```
/home/test/tmp/
```

(and other file-path like patterns, that need trailing and leading slashes, but no doubles. E.g. `/home/test/tmp/` passes through, but `/home/test/tmp` gets a trailing slash, etc.)

Using a triple regex;

```
s,^/*,/,;  #prefix
s,/*$,/,; #suffix
s,/+,/,g; #double slashes anywhere else.
```

Gives us the right result:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = 'home/////teledyne/tmp/';
$str =~ s,^/*,/,;    #prefix
$str =~ s,/*$,/,;    #suffix
$str =~ s,/+,/,g;    #double slashes anywhere else.
print $str;
```

But if I try and combine these patterns using alternation, I get:

```
s,(^/*|/+|/*$),/,g
```

Which looks like it *should* work... it actually doesn't, and I get a double trailing slash.

But adding a zero width match, it works fine:

```
s,(^/*|/+|\b/*$),/,g;
```

Can anyone help me understand what's happening differently in the alternation group, and is there a possible gotcha with just leaving that `\b` in there?

Comment: Your single regex transforms `"/"` to `"//"`, for similar reasons.

Comment: As others have answered your query, I thought I would point out that your initial 'Using a triple regex' gives the correct result is actually flawed.  Both your prefix and suffix are looking for zero or more slashes at the start or end of the string when in fact you want to be looking for the absence of the slash at these points.  So for the prefix it would have been more correct to look for :- s,^([^/]),/\1, .... This will check that there is not slash at the front and then add it plus the found character back again.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that the `/+` alternation under `/g` matches the last slash – and the search then goes on because of the presence of the anchor. It continues from the position after the last substitution, thus after the last slash.  That search matches zero slashes at `$` and adds `/`.

We can see this by

```
perl -wE'
    $_ = "home/dir///end/"; 
    while (m{( ^/* | /+ | /*$ )}gx) { say "Got |$1| at ", pos }
'
```

which prints  (with aligned `at ...` for readability)

```
Got ||    at 0
Got |/|   at 5
Got |///| at 11
Got |/|   at 15
Got ||    at 15
```

With the actual substitution

```
s{( ^/* | /+ | /*$ )}{ say "Got |$1| at ", pos; q(/) }egx
```

the numbers differ as they refer to positions in the intermediate strings, where the last two

```
...
Got |/| at 14
Got ||  at 15
```

are telling.

I don't see what can go wrong with having `\b`, as in the question or as `/*\b$`.

---

This is an interesting question, but I'd like to add that all these details are avoided by

```
$_ = '/' . (join '/', grep { /./ } split '/', $_) . '/'  for @paths;
```

Comment: @Sobrique I added to my post what I think shows it far more clearly than the original verbal statements alone.  Just letting you know in case you didn't get to see the change.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single regex to do all:

```
s='home/////test/tmp/'
perl -pe 's~^(?!/)|(?<!/)$|/{2,}~/~g' <<< "$s"
/home/test/tmp/

s='home/test/tmp'
perl -pe 's~^(?!/)|(?<!/)$|/{2,}~/~g' <<< "$s"
/home/test/tmp/
```

**Regex Breakup:**

```
^(?!/) # Line start if not followed by /
|
(?<!/)$ # Line end if not preceded by /
|
/{2,} # 2 or more /
```